# how do I make the floating header not show when the page gets smaller without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a floating header and it shows with the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('#floatingHeader').show();
        } else {
            $('#floatingHeader').hide();
        }
    });
```

In this floating header I have a filter drop down - when I am half way down the page I use the filter - I filter the results to 1 row of results and the page gets smaller - but the above scrip doesn't get executed - it only works when you scroll - how do I make the floating header not show when the page gets smaller without scrolling??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bind and the event names.

```
$(window).bind("scroll resize", function () {...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZATNp/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Document ReSize Event Plugin [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/documentresize).

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#floatingHeader').show();
    } else {
        $('#floatingHeader').hide();
    }
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
})();
```

You could do something like the above - carry out scrollTop checks on a repeated timer.